# Where does a Facebook user likes have been stored when using django_facebook and django-celery?

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-celery

I am developing a Facebook canvas application.
I'm a little bit confused on the process of storing a user's likes using the frameworks django_facebook and CELERY. 
I have set  `FACEBOOK_CELERY_STORE = True` in my settings.py.
and add app `djcelery` in my INSTALLED_APPS

```
@facebook_required(canvas=True)
def home(request,graph):

    facebook = FacebookUserConverter(graph)

    print "facebooklikes",facebook.get_likes() //This lists out all the likes of users
```

Where does these user's likes stored? There are many celery tables in my MySQL database. But not any of them have stored these data.

Answer (score 2):

Likes are not stored with this method, and `Celery` is not used for intermediate data processing. Data is requested from Facebook API and returned to you.

Likes can be stored with `get_and_store_likes` or `store_likes` methods, where `Celery` is used for asyncronous calls and inbetween data storage. At the end of a call, likes will be stored in `FacebookLike` model. Likes will be stored one record per a user like, from `user_id` to `facebook_id` field.

As a consequence, a table you are looking for is named `django_facebook_facebooklike`.

I found `django-facebook` package poorly documented, so no link to the docs. One can consult [source code](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook) for details.

Comment: I changed my code to :                                          `facebook = FacebookUserConverter(graph)
facebook.get_and_store_friends(request.user)`                               And it gives me error "[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"